# Overloaded operator<< returning ostream&

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I had the following code in a sample application:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const ReferenceTest& rt)
{
    os << rt.counter;  //In this scenario, rt has a public int called counter
}
```

I was surprised to learn that this code compiled without issue using GCC 4.6.1.  It fails when using Visual Studio 2010 for the reason I would have expected, namely that I'm not returning a reference to an ostream.  However, the output for the program when compiled for the two platforms is identical (I have a trivial main() that writes test output).

Which is standards compliant?  Am I missing something obvious here?

-Derek

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  Wouldn't the failure to return something from any (non-void) function qualify as a compile-time error?  I would have thought that this would justify more than a warning.  Agreed about -Wall though.

Comment: Also, is the runtime behavior a result of clever compilation (as David suggested), or coincidental (K-ballo)?  It seems like it's bordering on overstepping its bounds if it is in fact trying to "fix" my code for me...

Comment: A good compiler will try very hard to fix your code when it detects a problem. This however is undefined behavior. A bad compiler might do nothing, say nothing. A nasty compiler might insert a call to `degauss_hard_drive()` and say nothing. Undefined behavior means the compiler can be nice to you and reject your code, be kinda nice to you and "fix" your code, be mean to you and eject the drive that contains the code. Anything and everything is OK when it comes to the compiler's response to undefined behavior.

Comment: Fair enough....from a usability/correctness standpoint though, is  there a reason why the compiler shouldn't opt for the error?  It seems like the choice with the least possibility for unintended behavior would be to refuse to proceed.  A warning's better than nothing, I guess.  Maybe the real question is why this use case was deemed to be undefined behavior?

Comment: As K-ballo mentioned, checking whether a function does or does not flow off the end can be a very complex task. In fact, it is worse than complex. It is an impossible task. It is the halting problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you compile with warnings enabled? I get `warning: control reaches end of non-void function` with g++.

You certainly don't want a compiler to stop at the first error in your code. You want it to catch as many as it can in one swell foop. To do this, the compiler has to patch your buggy code so it can press on. In this case, the patch is obvious: Return the stream provided as an argument.

Never trust those "fixes" supplied for free by the compiler. They are anything but free. Fix your code instead.

And always compile with warnings enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Missing something other than the return statement? The lack of it is undefined behavior (I would even expect it to be a compile time error for such simple case). It may happen that the returned value from `os << rt.counter` expression happens to be placed at the same location where the return value for the whole `operator<<` is expected, making it work just by chance.

Comment: You are absolutely correct that this is undefined behavior. For whatever reason, the GNU suite deems reaching the end of a non-void function to be worthy of a mere warning rather than a comilation error. It makes up some return value and presses on with compilation.

Comment: @David Hammen: Checking whether the function can possibly ever reach the end of the function is quite a complex analisis. I'm sure the standard says that "no diagnostic is required".

Comment: There's no reason to say "no diagnostic is required." 6.6.3 para 2: "Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function." Diagnosis is not required for undefined behavior. That doesn't mean that when the compiler detects UB it must remain silent, or that it the compiler has to emit compiled code. Treating flowing off the end as a compiler error is perfectly OK, too.